# Copying a List of Dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, deep-copy

I'm importing some experimental data for processing and want to save the data from each experimental run as a dataframe in a list of dataframes. The code for importing the list of dataframes is given below.

```
 def get_dataframe(filepath):
  for path, dir, files in os.walk(filepath):
    continue

  #creating empty list of dataframes
  dataframes_list = []

  #appending each dataset as a new dataframe inside list
  for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".csv"):
      temp_df = pd.read_csv(filepath +f)

      #removing NaN values and adding final dataframe to the list of dataframes
      temp_df = temp_df.dropna(axis =0, how = "any")
      dataframes_list.append(temp_df)
```

After importing the list of dataframes, I want to normalise all the data for further use. But before I do this, I want to save a copy of the non-normalised dataframes list.

```
dataframes_list = get_dataframe('path')
dataframes_list_nonnorm = dataframes_list.copy()

display dataframes_list_nonnorm
```

Running the code below always seems to modify the non-normalised df list along with the original list. When I display both lists, they are the same values (normalised values)

```
dataframes_list = z_scaled_norm(dataframes_list)

display(dataframes_list)
display(dataframes_list_nonnorm)
```

How do I store the list of dataframes such that future modifications do not affect the copy made? I have tried deepcopy and it did not work. I suspect that this is because the objects in my list are mutable. Is there a way to save the copy of the dataframes list as a tuple? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `dataframes_list.copy()` copies the list object, a shallow copy, the objects being referred to by the list (i.e. the dataframes) are not copied. You could do something like `dataframes_list_nonnorm = [df.copy() for df in dataframes_list]`

Comment: "I have tried deepcopy and it did not work." I'm not sure I believe that. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is what I tried

from copy import deepcopy
dataframes_list_nonnorm = dataframes_list.copy.deepcopy()

kept getting this error: builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'deepcopy'

tried this: 
dataframes_list_nonnorm_train = []
for dataframe in dataframes_list_train:
  dataframes_list_nonnorm_train.append(dataframe.copy.deepcopy())

i also tried .copy(deep=True) and got the error "copy takes no keyword arguments".

Am I using deepcopy incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you doing `dataframes_list.copy.deepcopy()` That is totally incorrect. You just imported `deepcopy`, so just use `deepcopy(dataframes_list)`. But again, you don't need to do that, you can just do `dataframes_list_nonnorm = [df.copy() for df in dataframes_list]`